# Angular Universal with vesrion 14 Meta tags not display on page view source but able to see in inspect webpage

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am facing same issue with angular universal; I am able to see the meta data in inspect but not in view source code. can you please help and elaborate your answer.

```
 updateDescription(desc: string, keywords: string, title: string) {
    this.title.setTitle(title + ' | MedicHire');
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: desc })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: keywords })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:title', content: title })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:description', content: desc })
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9MFu.png)

Angular univeral should display data in viewpage source(Ctrl +U)

Comment: Do you test it in production ? Is Angular Universal correctly running ?

Comment: @user1075296 I am using this command to test  ( npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr )

Comment: If there is any other way please let me know

Comment: Could you show your viewpage source content ? Also, can you show where is your updateDescription called ?

Comment: Is your angular app a PWA? Do you see the metatags when view source code + CTRL + F5?

Comment: I am getting metadata tag when add static values but I am using http call it is not working. I think http calls are loaded late that why may be ?

Comment: I have also tried angular resolver to load data but it is still not working.